# Hibernate and DB2 connection

Tags: hibernate, connection, db2

I am really in a great problem here. I am connecting Db2 thriugh Hibernate.

Below is my hibernate.cfg.xml file code for db2 connection

```
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/hla</property>     
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:db2://192.262.3.12:34333/dbname;create=true</property>
    <property name="connection.username">Db2admin</property>
    <property name="connection.password">******</property>
```

When I try to create session

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
```

It throws exception. I am attaching part of that exception. Hope it will help.

```
16:15:33,749 ERROR [DispatchAction] Dispatch[/list] to method 'listComponents' returned an exception
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:615)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.dispatchMethod(DispatchAction.java:269)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:182)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:797)
Caused by: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sit.util.HibernateUtil (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:123)
    at com.core.dao.Dao.getAlls(Unknown Source)
    at com.sit.visualisation.actions.VisualListAction(VisualListAction.java:99)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: 
java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.pirean.sit.util.HibernateUtil"  seems like this class is not where it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you defining a "data source" and the connection properties (jdbc url, username, password)? You should either consume a data source provided by your container (preferred) or let Hibernate connect directly to the database (useful in standalone environments).

In your case,  the exception is that Hibernate cannot get connections from JNDI using the name "jdbc/hla". So, check your application server's configuration. If you remove the data source configuration, Hibernate will try to connect directly to the database, using the other information you provided (jdbc url, username, password).

```
<!-- Hibernate will try to get "jdbc/hla" from the application server -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">jdbc/hla</property>     

<!-- Hibernate will try to connect directly to the database -->
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:db2://192.262.3.12:34333/dbname;create=true</property>
<property name="connection.username">Db2admin</property>
<property name="connection.password">******</property>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was also thinking of the mistake you mentioned here. So what properties should I give in hibernate.cfg.xml file?

Comment: It depends. What do you want to do? To use connections provided by your container, or to let Hibernate manage it?

Comment: I want to do it. No matter which way i use. Please guide me any method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the stacktrace is incomplete... the problem is that com.sit.util.HibernateUtil class' iniziatization is throwing an exception, which is probably described after:

```
Caused by: 
java.lang.Throwable: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```